# can Alfresco be used as a JCR implementation?

Tags: alfresco, jcr

as the title says, I want to replace an `JCR` implementation (Jackrabbit Oak) with Alfresco. is it possible? and what is the practice and you recommendations to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this page](https://www.alfresco.com/services/subscription/technical-support/product-support-status), support for JCR and JCR-RMI in Alfresco was at end-of-maintenance in 2014.